# Get xargs sequence number

Tags: curl, xargs

In GNU Parallel you have:

```
seq()    -     sequence number of job
```

Thanks to this I can run `wget` in `parallel` using:

```
parallel -a urls.txt -j8 wget -q {} -O '{=$_=sprintf("file%05d.ts", $job->seq())=}'
```

..and it will name files like so:

```
file00001.ts
file00002.ts
...
file00999.ts
```

---

Now, how can I get the sequence number of `xargs`?

Example:

```
xargs -P 8 -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
cat urls.txt |
  parallel --shellquote |
  parallel --shellquote |
  perl -pe 's/(.*)/$1.sprintf(" -O file%05d.ts",++$t)/e' |
  xargs -P 8 -n 1 -I {} bash -c "wget {}"
```

The 2 `--shellquote`s are needed if you have urls with special chars like space and ':

```
http://pi.dk/? '
```